# I see only : "Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'"

Tags: php, mysql

**My site'Internet'** workd well during 20 day.
but today it have a problem with only : "Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'".

the same code in localhost is working well. but after i upload to site'internet'.
it have the same error.

I see only: "Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'"

and can not find the solution.

### thanks.

Sorry, after debug careffuly,
I found the reason.

Click upload_file. but variable: $_FILES is not set the value ---> can not upload file to the database ----> load from database error ----> Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'.

Thanks alls, but i can not find why the $_FILES is not set the value "Server in internet" but $_FILES is set the value in "Server in local host"

Comment: Have you checked the database to see if that table contains that column?

Comment: There is no 'Array' column in your sql table.

Comment: How can you explain the situation: "localhost run and Internet not run".
I have check the field list. and use the file database from localhost

Comment: Your site is called "internet"?

Comment: the site on Internet and localhost.
the site is working well in localhost but when i upload to internet with same database. the Error connection above

Comment: What you posted was the function. Write the code where you called it. Where the $url and $id coming from? And there's no array word in your sql. So most probably the error lies elsewhere.

Comment: Echo $url and $id to know if those are correct. Also, you can echo the complete sql query and test it.

Comment: print_r($result); the text "Resource id#14"
i see the error after the code line:
mysql_result($result,0);
I don't know , may ben the diffirent of MYSQL Version between local and Internet????????????????????

Answer (score 0):

Please check the table fields in both localhost and server. If the table fields differ from localhost to server database then this kind of problem may rise.

Comment: thank Anjuman, I import file database from localhost. and certainly, site PHP in localhost is working well